# stringWithContentsofurl generate leaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

im trying to get data via

> NSString *string = [NSString
>   stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL
>   URLWithString: url]];

everything works fine, but when I run it with performance tool, it finds leaks on this line.

Here is whole mehod I use:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getOutputImagesData: (URLParserImagesData) data
{
    NSString *type = (data == URLParserImagesDataLatestImage) ? @"img" : @"size";

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s%s%s", [URLParserSiteURLforCategories UTF8String], [URLParserType UTF8String], [type UTF8String]];

    //i get leaks here      
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    NSArray *imagesTemp = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    NSMutableDictionary *outputImages = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(NSString *img in imagesTemp)
    {
    NSArray *splitStrings = [img componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];

    if(data == URLParserImagesDataImagesCount)
    {
        NSNumber *integerValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[splitStrings objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
        [outputImages setObject: integerValue forKey: [splitStrings objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else
        [outputImages setObject: [splitStrings objectAtIndex:1] forKey: [splitStrings objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    return outputImages;
}
```

Comment: You can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", URLParserSiteURLforCategories, ...]` to avoid the `-UTF8String`'s.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much. All I had to do, was put @ insted of s and UTF8String.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithContentsOfURL:` is [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#jumpTo_2). Try to use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`  or `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` instead.